# ELF file TLS and LOAD program sections

Tags: linux, elf, glibc, thread-local-storage

```
int i;
int main() {
     return i;    
}
```

After `-static` compile `readelf -l` shows program headers from elf:

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0xxxxx30
There are 6 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x79868 0x79868 R E 0x1000
 > LOAD           0x079f94 0x080c2f94 0x080c2f94 0x0078c 0x02254 RW  0x1000  <<
  NOTE           0x0000f4 0x080480f4 0x080480f4 0x00020 0x00020 R   0x4
 > TLS            0x079f94 0x080c2f94 0x080c2f94 0x00010 0x0002c R   0x4     <<
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x4
  PAX_FLAGS      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000     0x4

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .note.ABI-tag .init .text __libc_freeres_fn .fini .rodata __libc_subfreeres __libc_atexit .eh_frame .gcc_except_table
   01     .tdata .ctors .dtors .jcr .data.rel.ro .got .got.plt .data .bss __libc_freeres_ptrs
   02     .note.ABI-tag
   03     .tdata .tbss
```

Can somebody explain, why the 2nd and 4th program headers does intersect (they begin with same offset 0x079f94 and VirtAddr 0x080c2f94).

Also, the segment section `.tdata`  is referred twice.

How `PT_TLS` and `PT_LOAD` will be loaded for first thread (the program itself)?
Where does `.tbss` lie in the memory?

Comment: looks like tls placed on HEAP...

Comment: You can check how TLS is loaded by strace grepping for `set_thread_area` syscall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First `.tdata` section - is an "initial image" of TLS data. It is the initial values of TLS vars, which will be used in every thread (and in main thread too).  In the `crt` (I assume) there is a copying of TLS initial image into TLS of main thread. Same code is in `pthread_create`.

PT_TLS is not loaded, because PT_LOAD does and PT_LOAD already contains this PT_TLS. I think that PT_TLS is for initial image - because it is shorter than entire thread-local data  ( tbss+tdata > size(PT_TLS) ).

Answer (score 4):

As far as mapping memory regions are concerned, I think the kernel only looks at PT_LOAD segments and mmaps them. (kernel also looks at PT_GNU_STACK to figure out if stack should be mapped with Execute permission or not.) Have a look at binfmt_elf.c:load_elf_binary() for relevant code.

PT_TLS segment is read by libc to figure out memory to be setup of Thread-Local storage. Have a look at __libc_setup_tls() for relevant code.

PT_TLS segment intersects with the PT_LOAD segment so that it gets mapped into the process memory.

Answer (score 1):

TLS stands for "Thread-Local Storage".

To permit association of separate copies of data allocated at compile-time with individual threads of execution, thread-local storage sections can be used to specify the size and initial contents of such data. Implementations need not support thread-local storage. A PT_TLS program entry has the following members:

```
Member      Value
 p_offset   File offset of the TLS initialization image
 p_vaddr    Virtual memory address of the TLS initialization image
 p_paddr    reserved
 p_filesz   Size of the TLS initialization image
 p_memsz    Total size of the TLS template
 p_flags    PF_R
 p_align    Alignment of the TLS template
```

The TLS template is formed from the combination of all sections with the flag SHF_TLS. The portion of the TLS template that holds initialized data is the TLS initialization image. (The remaining portion of the TLS template is one or more sections of type SHT_NOBITS.)

Comment: ok. but "How PT_TLS and PT_LOAD will be loaded for first thread (the programm itself)?" is the question.